Error in recvfrom function when executing traceroute ICMP ping code in C code
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/ip_icmp.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define PACKET_SIZE 64
#define MAX_HOPS 30
#define TIMEOUT 3 // 3초로 타임아웃 증가

// ICMP 패킷 생성
void create_icmp_packet(struct icmphdr *icmp_hdr) {
    memset(icmp_hdr, 0, sizeof(struct icmphdr));
    icmp_hdr->type = ICMP_ECHO;
    icmp_hdr->un.echo.id = getpid();
    icmp_hdr->un.echo.sequence = 0;
    icmp_hdr->checksum = 0;

    // 체크섬 계산
    int packet_size = sizeof(struct icmphdr);
    unsigned short *buf = (unsigned short *)icmp_hdr;
    unsigned int checksum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < packet_size / 2; i++) {
        checksum += buf[i];
    }
    icmp_hdr->checksum = ~((checksum & 0xFFFF) + (checksum >> 16));
}

// 목적지 도메인 주소를 얻어옴
int resolve_hostname(const char *hostname, struct sockaddr_in *dest) {
    struct hostent *host_entity;
    if ((host_entity = gethostbyname(hostname)) == NULL) {
        perror("gethostbyname");
        return -1;
    }
    dest->sin_family = AF_INET;
    dest->sin_port = htons(0);
    dest->sin_addr.s_addr = *(long *)host_entity->h_addr;
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Usage: %s <hostname>\n", argv[0]);
        return -1;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in dest;
    if (resolve_hostname(argv[1], &dest) < 0) {
        return -1;
    }

    int sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMP);
    if (sockfd < 0) {
        perror("socket");
        return -1;
    }

    struct timeval timeout;
    timeout.tv_sec = TIMEOUT;
    timeout.tv_usec = 0;
    if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (const char *)&timeout, sizeof(timeout)) < 0) {
        perror("setsockopt SO_RCVTIMEO");
        close(sockfd);
        return -1;
    }
    
    int recv_buffer_size = 1024 * 1024; // 1MB
    if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, &recv_buffer_size, sizeof(recv_buffer_size)) < 0) {
        perror("setsockopt SO_RCVBUF");
        close(sockfd);
        return -1;
    }

    char sendbuf[PACKET_SIZE];
    char recvbuf[PACKET_SIZE];
    struct sockaddr_in recv_addr;
    socklen_t addrlen = sizeof(recv_addr);

    for (int ttl = 1; ttl <= MAX_HOPS; ttl++) {
        // TTL 설정
        if (setsockopt(sockfd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_TTL, &ttl, sizeof(ttl)) < 0) {
            perror("setsockopt IP_TTL");
            close(sockfd);
            return 1;
        }

        // ICMP 패킷 생성 및 전송
        struct icmphdr *icmp_hdr = (struct icmphdr *)sendbuf;
        create_icmp_packet(icmp_hdr);
        if (sendto(sockfd, sendbuf, sizeof(struct icmphdr), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&dest, sizeof(dest)) < 0) {
            perror("sendto");
            continue;  // 패킷 전송 실패 시 계속 진행
        }

        ssize_t recv_bytes = recvfrom(sockfd, recvbuf, PACKET_SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&recv_addr, &addrlen);
        if (recv_bytes < 0) {
            printf("recvfrom failed with errno: %d\n", errno);
            if (errno == EAGAIN || errno == EWOULDBLOCK) {
                printf("%d * * * (Timeout)\n", ttl); // 타임아웃
            } else {
                perror("recvfrom");
            }
            continue;
        } else {
            printf("Received %zd bytes\n", recv_bytes);
            
            // 응답 출력
            struct iphdr *ip_hdr = (struct iphdr *)recvbuf;
            struct icmphdr *recv_icmp_hdr = (struct icmphdr *)(recvbuf + (ip_hdr->ihl << 2));

            char ip_str[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
            inet_ntop(AF_INET, &recv_addr.sin_addr, ip_str, sizeof(ip_str));
            printf("%d %s\n", ttl, ip_str);

            // ICMP 타입에 따른 처리
            if (recv_icmp_hdr->type == ICMP_TIME_EXCEEDED) {
                printf("%d %s (TTL exceeded)\n", ttl, ip_str);
            } else if (recv_icmp_hdr->type == ICMP_ECHOREPLY) {
                printf("Trace complete.\n");
                break;
            } else {
                printf("Unexpected ICMP type: %d\n", recv_icmp_hdr->type);
            }
        }
    }

    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}


I am writing a code for a function that does the traceroute -I option with the following code. However, unlike running traceroute -I, the value has not been received by returning -1 from TTL 2 to recvfrom.

It is judged that there is no network problem because the traceroute -I command operates normally when running on the same terminal.


When running wireshark, you can see that the packet is received as follows.
This is the only difference between the two packets.



Please don't post pictures of text, instead copy/paste the text into your question and place \``noneon the line above a text block and```on the line below it so it formats in fixed width font (thenone` just specifies no syntax highlight). You can also indent the blocks by 4-characters to format as fixed text.

Have a look at ICMP sockets (linux), it appears you need SOCK_DGRAM instead of SOCK_RAW to avoid socket permission issues. If you are running as root to avoid that -- that's not the best idea.

Please [edit] your question and also show the errno value and perror output.
